# F1 Visa and Bank statement requirement

Tags: usa, visa

Well, in USA, I have to show that I can pay the tuition fee and also support myself. If I receive tuition waiver,I need not pay tuition fee, but I have to support myself. If I receive a TAship offer, then I can show that and say that I have my means to support myself in USA. The TAship amount is enough for the living expenses in the United States.

When I face the visa interview, will I have to bring bank statement to show some amount of money? How much?  My economic condition is not good.

Comment: No idea, but it may be a month or more before you're paid once you start an assistantship so you're going to need some resources (plus flights, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can only work 10 hours a week on F1 visa. And, it is barely enough to cover your living expenses actually. I would suggest contacting International Students Office and ask them about your current situation and how much you need to declare to get your SEVIS and I-20.

In my case I declared a year of tuition + estimated living expenses, which amounted to $46500. You however, do not have to put this money into a US bank or whatsoever. You just have to show that you have *sufficient* funds to support yourself and won't be taking advantage of wellfare or working illegally.

Comment: It's 20 hours per week, not 10 during academic session, You can work full-time during breaks, summers.

Comment: @mkennedy you might be right, when I worked as a TA back in 2014, we were restricted to 10 hours maximum, that's why I said 10 hours. Thanks for the insight.